# Install azure cli via brew not working in mac m1

Tags: macos, pip, homebrew, azure-cli, apple-m1

I have be trying to install azure cli in new mac m1. But it fails. I get the following error

```
brew reinstall azure-cli
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/azure-cli/manifests/2.22.1
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/azure-cli/blobs/sha256:1980c967
==> Downloading from https://pkg-containers-az.githubusercontent.com/ghcr1/blobs
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Reinstalling azure-cli 
==> Pouring azure-cli--2.22.1.arm64_big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/azure-cli/2.22.1: 19,449 files, 329.3MB
```

After Pouring it just stops. I also tried to install using pip3 and I can install that successfully but when I type "az" command I get the following error

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/az: line 2: 64784 Killed: 9               AZ_INSTALLER=HOMEBREW /opt/homebrew/Cellar/azure-cli/2.22.1/libexec/bin/python -m azure.cli "$@"
```

Comment: I finally found the solution. My python3 wasn't installed via brew. So first uninstalled brew and python3. Then installed brew again(before that made sure Rosetta 2 is working). Then tried `brew doctor`. There was error saying `/usr/... `then, I deleted those files. Once successfully removed/deleted `brew doctor` will run fine. After that installed azure-cli using brew it should run fine. Also, follow all the suggestions when you execute `brew install azure-cli`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments: My python3 wasn't installed via brew. So first uninstalled brew and python3. Then installed brew again(before that made sure Rosetta 2 is working). Then tried brew doctor. There was error saying /usr/... then, I deleted those files. Once successfully removed/deleted brew doctor will run fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble with this too, I took the following steps to install and access the azure cli (I did this on an M1 Mac, OS 13.2.1):

- Uninstalled brew with `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"`
- Ran `brew doctor`
- Deleted files that brew doctor was complaining about (copied the path and opened up a finder window and typed `CMD shift G` and pasted the path here then pressed enter)
- Ran `brew doctor` again and it didn't complain
- Ran `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"` to install homebrew
- Ran  `(echo; echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"') >> /Users/somefolder/.zprofile eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"` to add homebrew to my PATH
- Installed rosetta
- Next, If I typed `where python3` to see a list of other Python3 installs on my machine and their interpreter paths, anything installed by Homebrew should include the word homebrew in the path e.g. `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3`
- Installed a version of python with homebrew if it didn't already exist `brew install python@3.11`. I would delete an exisiting version with `brew install python@3.11` if it already exisited.
- If you're executing commands in a terminal within VSC ensure you've added the interpreter path e.g. `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3` and select it for the terminal session.
- Ran `brew update && brew install azure-cli`
- Ran  `az --help` to ensure the install worked